# TFP401PZP: Unable to get proper video output, ghost screen/distorted pixels

Tags: display, signal-integrity, texas-instruments, interface, hdmi

I have designed my own display driver board using a TI [TFP401PZP](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tfp401.pdf) TMDS DVI receiver/deserializer which is connected to a 24-bit, parallel RGB, 7 inch capacitive touch display with a resolution of 800x480.

The power distribution is perfectly done to all segments. The driver board is designed on a two-layer PCB (the back layer is dedicated to only ground plane).

Pin configurations:

- DFO = pulled down for continuous clock
- nPDO = connected to SCDT for normal operation/drivers on
- ST = pulled up for high drive strength
- PIXS = pulled down for 1 px/clk
- nSTAG = pulled high for normal simultaneous even/odd pixel output
- OCK_INV = pulled high for: latches output data on rising ODCK edge

My findings through oscilloscope after changing another probe:

- ODCK = 34 MHz
- VSYNC = 60 Hz
- HSYNC = 31.04 kHz
- DE = 28.81 kHz (Vpp = 2.24 v)

I also set the EDID to external EEPROM with 800x480 resolution.

At the output I'm getting distorted video (ghost screen/pixel mismatch) with greenish horizontal lines. I've also shared the video output screen and circuit board with schematic.

My schematic:
[image]

**The distorted video output/black screen:**

[image]

**video output after 5 mins of display on time when ODCK, HSYNC, VSYNC disappears:**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of EDID you loaded? Why do you have a HDMI connector on a device which cannot have HDMI support? Are you powering something from HDMI 5V? Why do you have the EDID EPROM on 3.3V supply? Why do you have a 10K resistor on HPD? This isn't a compliant design in many ways.

Comment: @Justme TFP401PZP is a TMDS DVI/HDMI receiver/deserializer bridge IC . It converts digital video signals into upto 24 bit analog RGB signals for display.

Comment: It is a DVI compliant receiver. I don't see it being advertized as HDMI compliant. Anyway, what EDID you uploaded to EEPROM, and do comment on the rest of my questions to you in order to find our what is wrong. The 2 sided PCB is also a hazard for high speed signals that require good impedance matching.

Comment: @Justme HDMI I2C is directly connected to EEPROM I2C to store EDID info and uses 3.3v from on board supply though it can be connected to HDMI 5v.  
According to The HDMI Specification 1.4b for hotplug detection a 10K must be pulled high to 5v. 
About the design, I have checked tons of datasheet and reference designs also on two layer PCB.
E.g.  Adafruit's TFP401 HDMI/DVI Decoder to 40-Pin TTL Breakout and Waveshare's 7 inch Usb compliant touch display. These two are based on double sided PCB.

Comment: I have used the reference EDID provided by Adafruit and changed some properties compatible to my display.

Comment: I can see the schematics, that is why I am asking why is it designed in a way that a HDMI device should not be designed.  DDC is a 5V bus. And I am 100% sure no HDMI specification tells to put a 10k resistor to pull high. And I can't know where to find some reference EDID and know what changes you made to it, if they are made correctly. Please provide a link to some EDID that I can examine, preferably your EDID.

Comment: I have used the EDID from the link https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tfp401-hdmi-slash-dvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-display/editing-the-edid

Comment: @Justme After looking through the IC datasheet, I found that TFP401x is a TMDS digital receiver that is used in digital flat panel display systems to receive and decode TMDS-encoded RGB pixel data streams,hence it can be used in both DVI/HDMI interface that incorporates high-speed low-voltage differential pairs.

Comment: @JohnMist I can also read the data sheet. Where does it say it officially supports  HDMI protocol? Unless you are aware, HDMI and DVI protocols are different, and not all DVI-only receivers are capable of properly ignoring HDMI additions to the protocol. But fortunately, the EDID does not list HDMI protocol support, so all compliant devices must send DVI protocol. Unless they are non-compliant. But also this device is not compliant because it must list support for HDMI because it has a HDMI connector.

Comment: @justme As far as i know,  Winstar, Waveshare and Adafruit has also used the same IC and I also have taken that design asreference .

Comment: @Justme I'm aware because many of our clients use waveshare HDMI display for automation that includes the same TFP401x IC.
Or else you can go through this appl. note under the technical docs.-https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla325c/slla325c.pdf?ts=1707215244574&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTFP401A

Comment: @JohnMist My point is confirmed by the application note wording. It says, how to connect a DVI or HDMI source to a LVDS panel. HDMI sources are required to send DVI into non-HDMI displays, so it does not mean you can make a HDMI display with this chip, only that HDMI sources can be connected to it. And further down in the notes, the incoming TMDS data must be DVI compliant, and not contain HDMI island data. So, you can't make display that can receive HDMI data. And the display is not officially allowed to have a HDMI connector then, as a HDMI display must be able tl receive HDMI data.

Comment: My HDMI source is Raspberry pi 3b+ . I am not transmitting any data over it.  My only purpose is to connect the Rpi to the display via HDMI and show the video output.

Comment: What does the eye-diagram look like?

Comment: @Aryan - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either [your answer](/help/self-answer) or another answer. Áccepting an answer shows you don't need more help & you consider the problem solved. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So , I figured out what was going wrong.

In my second iteration of the PCB layout, the driver board is now operating flawlessly. I made some minor adjustments, such as adding a 90 ohm CMR filter next to the HDMI input differential pair and tuned all the differential traces to a length of 60mm with proper impedance matching.(issue was the improper routing of Diff. pair)

Answer (score 1):

There might be many issues.

Obviously the HSYNC and VSYNC should not run at same rate.

If you used the stock Adafruit EDID, it will only list a 32.00 MHz DTD, so if the Raspberry Pi outputs anything else, it might not have read the EDID correctly.

Which might be due to the hardware issues that the EEPROM is powered with 3.3V but DDC is a 5V bus, and the display side DDC pull-ups are incorrect.

It might also be that the Raspberry Pi was unable to read the EDID if display  was connected before it was powered up, because HPD is always tied high, but the EDID was powered separately.

Or it might be that the HPD is tied high with incorrect resistance so RPi cannot see that a display is plugged in.

The chip Reserved pin should be tied high but the resistor reads NC so it might not be tied high.

If you did edit the EDID contents, the changes could have errors, or the checksum could be incorrect.

Also the RPi must be made sure to output only TMDS video that uses DVI protocol to the chip, in the application notes it is said that the chip cannot receive TMDS video using HDMI protocol.

Comment: I have programed my EEPROM with Adafruit EDID and connected it on Waveshare and it is working perfectly. So may be the issue is not with EDID.

I have almost the same configuration as Waveshare. 
 EEPROM is powered with 3.3V and I2C bus is pulled up to 3.3V

Comment: @Aryan Yes and since the E-DDC is a 5V bus, the pull-ups to 3.3V and the EEPROM powered with 3.3V will clamp the bus and not allow 5V voltages, so the bus or anything else that is outside the specs means it does not have to work.

Comment: Okay I will have to change the configuration and will let you know the result by tomorrow.

Comment: @Aryan It could be all the other things as well. Especially the pin called "Reserved".

Comment: I followed your instructions and connected the eeprom to the 5 volt bus as well as configured the EDID, however the screen still appears to be in dark mode with vertical aligned pixels. If there is anything else that you think I should test, do suggest.

Comment: @Aryan What about all the other things I already mentioned what are wrong? Like the reserved pin that must be high, is it really high?

Comment: Yes according to datasheet Pin no.99-RSVD pin must be pulled up to power rail. I have tried everything but could not find the issue

Comment: Oscilloscope output: 
ODCK=34MHz,

DE=28.81KHz(VPP=2.27V),

HSYNC=31.04KHz,

VSYNC=60Hz,  


    The only issue with new driver board is that the clock, HSYNC, and VSYNC timings dissapear after few minutes(5min) of display on time.

Till 5 mins display stays in dark mode with some vertical lines after 5 mins display output transforms to the image posted above.

Comment: @Aryan Sounds like black picture coming out, until some screensaver hits in and video is turned off, which makes the TFT screen to be not driven at all and image fades as the TFT charges disappear. Please use another source, and make sure to force RPi output into **DVI** mode, the TMDS receiver **cannot understand HDMI** mode.

Comment: Yes, a black picture shows, however after a while it disappears and the screen changes to the image described above. I tried forcing the RPI output into DVI mode but had no results.